# Animation is not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, cabasicanimation

I implemented `corePlot` in `xcode` and I'm using the pie chart. I'm trying to create a 3d flip animation while the chart reloads. Here is the code:

```
CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
scaleAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[self.pieChart addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];

[self.pieChart reloadData];

CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
animation.duration = 1.0f;
[self.pieChart addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scale"];
```

I didn't get desirable effects. I think what's happening is, both animations are happening at once. (Though I'm not sure that is what's happening.)

Also, is it possible to add z-depth? If so, how?

**Update**

I tried the follwoing:

```
CABasicAnimation *currentAnition = (CABasicAnimation *)anim;
if (currentAnition == self.scaleAnimation {...}
```

And it didn't work.

Comment: The way your code is now, both animations will start at nearly the same time. If you want the second one to run after the first one completes, call the second one from the delegate method, animationDidStop:finished:. Make your controller (or wherever this code is) the delegate of scaleAnimation.

Comment: This isn't the only animation I have. How can I check which animation finished?

Comment: The animation that called the delegate method is passed in, so you can check if it is scaleAnimation or not (you'll have to make scaleAnimation a property or ivar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAAnimation is KVC compliant, so we can store whether you're starting or finishing for lookup in the delegate methods:

```
{
    CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
    [scaleAnimation setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"scaleAnimation"];
    // set the delegate
    scaleAnimation.delegate = self;
    scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
    scaleAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
    scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [self.pieChart addAnimation:scaleAnimation forKey:@"scale"];
    [self.pieChart reloadData];
}

- (void)runSecondAnimation
{
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
    [animation setValue:@(YES) forKey:@"secondAnimation"];
    animation.delegate = self;
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
    animation.duration = 1.0f;
    [self.pieChart addAnimation:animation forKey:@"scale"];
}

/* Called when the animation either completes its active duration or
 * is removed from the object it is attached to (i.e. the layer). 'flag'
 * is true if the animation reached the end of its active duration
 * without being removed. */

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    BOOL scaleAnimation = [[anim valueForKey:@"scaleAnimation"] boolValue];
    if (scaleAnimation) {
        [self runSecondAnimation];
    }
    BOOL secondAnimation = [[anim valueForKey:@"secondAnimation"] boolValue];
    if (secondAnimation) {
        [self runThirdAnimation];
    }
}
```

And remember you have also:

```
/* Called when the animation begins its active duration. */
- (void)animationDidStart:(CAAnimation *)anim;
```